# Azure Synapse Analytics SQL Database function to get match between two delimited lists

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm using Azure Synapse Analytics SQL Database.  I'm aware I can't use selects in a scalar function (hence the error `The SELECT statement is not allowed in user-defined functions`).  I'm looking for a work-around since this function does not rely on any tables.  The goal is  a scalar function that takes two delimited lists parameters, a delimiter parameter and returns 1 if the lists have one or more matching items, and returns 0 if no matches are found.

```
--The SELECT statement is not allowed in user-defined functions
CREATE FUNCTION util.get_lsts_have_mtch
(
    @p_lst_1 VARCHAR(8000),
    @p_lst_2 VARCHAR(8000),
    @p_dlmtr CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS BIT
/***********************************************************************************************************
Description: This function returns 1 if two delimited lists have an item that exists in both lists.
--Example run: 
SELECT util.get_lsts_have_mtch('AB|CD|EF|GH|IJ','UV|WX|CD|IJ|YZ','|') -- returns 1, there's a match
SELECT util.get_lsts_have_mtch('AB|CD|EF|GH|IJ','ST|UV|WX|YZ','|') -- returns 0, there's no match
**********************************************************************************************************/
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @v_result BIT;
    -- *** CAN THIS BE ACCOMPLISHED EFFICIENTLY WITHOUT ANY SELECTS? ***
    SET @v_result = (SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                              FROM STRING_SPLIT(@p_lst_1, @p_dlmtr)       AS tokens_1
                                              INNER JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@p_lst_2, @p_dlmtr) AS tokens_2
                                                  ON     tokens_1.value = tokens_2.value)
                                     THEN 1
                                 ELSE 0
                            END) AS BIT);
    RETURN @v_result;
END;
```

Comment: Just use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and EXCEPT.

Answer (score 0):

I ditched the function and used this CASE statement.  I wanted a function to join on that would be reusable.  If anyone can find a function to do this, I will make that the accepted answer.

```
SELECT ...
FROM tbl_1
JOIN tbl_2
ON  
-- wanted: util.get_lsts_have_mtch(tbl_1.my_lst, tbl_2.my_lst, '|') = 1
-- but settled for:
CASE WHEN EXISTS 
          (SELECT [value] 
           FROM STRING_SPLIT(tbl_1.my_lst, '|') 
           INTERSECT 
           SELECT [value] 
           FROM STRING_SPLIT(tbl_2.my_lst, '|')) 
     THEN 1 
     ELSE 0 
     END = 1
```